# How to "layer" image in google sheets using checkboxes

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table of checkboxes (rows 1-3 and columns a-d) and I'm trying to make a layered image from each column - meaning that if for example, I check A1, B2, C3, and D1, four images will appear on top of each other in one specific cell. (each combination of a row and column has a different image)

I already managed to make it so that if I check a box, an image will appear using one long IFS formula. The problem is that it only shows the checked image that is the highest on the list in the ifs formula, not any other. Is there any way to layer images? In my case, there will be only one image per column, multiple per row.

edit: I want multiple images in one cell, using their transparency

Answer (score 0):

Your might want to clarify if by 'layering' you are referring to distributing multiple images in a cell (i.e. in a grid) or overlaying them (i.e. with transparency) as it's not clear to me. In any case if you are using the IMAGE function to attempt this by pulling images from a website then I don't think what you want to do is directly possible in the way you would like as:

- IMAGE only allows for one image per cell
- IFS (and IF as well) perform 'short-circuit evaluation', i.e. they stop at the first TRUE encountered

You might be able to achieve what you want with Apps Script, but that's beyond my capabilities.